# How to find the Django package

Tags: linux, django, bash, shell, pip

I work with ubuntu 12.04 and I  want to know whether Django is currently installed. I tried it like this at first:

```
$ python
>>> import django
>>> django
```

but I want to do it in the terminal. I don't want to use dpkg because the user might have installed it with python-pip. I already tried ***find*** and ***whereis*** but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write simple script using python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

try:
    import django
    print "found"
    print "path={0}".format(os.path.dirname(django.__file__))
    sys.exit(0)
except ImportError:
    print "not found"
    sys.exit(0)
```

then run script and check for exit code

```
$ python script.py
$ echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this question: [How do I find the location of Python module sources?][1]